# How can I spawn villagers in a particular building in the Captive Minecraft 1 challenge map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to spawn villagers in a particular building, in **Captive Minecraft 1**?  If so, I would really like some advice.

Comment: Please reform your question, for example, by including failed attempts at doing so, or the room structure you plan to house them in. Also, the extra signature is not required, we see your name in the corner :)

Answer (score -1):

Before-hand note: This was written to reply to the Previous Unedited Question about Spawning Villagers. If this does not help you, please refer to other answers, or siphon of these ones - for this case: Spawning Villagers in Captive Minecraft would be made possible if Cheats were Enabled.

## Solution 0, albeit laborious

Manually spawning Villagers with the Villager Egg.

But we don't want to be doing that all the time, do we? Plus, what about adventure maps - will we have to be there to spawn in mobs for other players just to advance the gameplay?
No, a much simpler method is in store...

## Solution 1 - The Real Method

Use a Command Block! Those pesky but lovable little kinder cubes that you often find tucked away in the highest heights in adventure maps.
To provide yourself with one, obviously having Cheats Enabled and in Creative Mode (to access the GUI), type: `/give @p command_block`.
Or if you're using a much older version of minecraft: `/give <Player Name> 137`

In the Command Block GUI, type the command: `/summon Villager x y z`, of course replacing the x, y and z with the appropriate coordinates of the designated location!

And really, that's it! You could loop your command by setting the Block Type to Repeat, or initialise it by instituting a redstone timing circuit. It's your choice.

## Solution 1 : Some Images documenting the Method

[image: The room (a little nice one, as well) with the designated spawn location]
[image: Literately manually spawning a Villager, not very fun...]
This was the literate manual spawning of a Villager... not very much fun to be had here.
[image: Spawning a Villager via a Command Block]
Now it gets interesting. The command can be seen above...
[image: Maximum Results! Successfully spawned. Houston, we're coming home!]
We've got maximum results. Which isn't enough, we can do better! What about more of these command blocks spawning them in different places? Yes... ideas ideas...

## Conclusion

If you have just skipped to the end hoping to have a recap of the answer... nope.avi

Come on! Read like a normal person. But, since I'm a nice person, I'll recap for you... :)
Use the command: `/summon Villager x y z`. Replace the x , y and z with the relevant coordinates. You can type this command either through the Command Bar or in a Command Block.

Thanks for reading.